# Java / Sql-server parameter binding does not work as expected

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, unicode, binding

We notice a strange behaviour in our application concerning bind parameters. We use Java with JDBC to connect to a Sql Server database. In a table cell we have the value 'µ', and we compare it with a bind parameter, which is also set to the value 'µ'.

Now, in a sql statement like *"... where value != ?"*, where 'value' is the value of 'µ' in the database and ? the bind variable, which is also set to 'µ', we notice that we get a record, though we would expect that 'µ' equals 'µ'.

The method that we use to fill the bind parameter is java.sql.PreparedStatement.setString(int, String).

[Some facts:](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b5/index.htm)

The character value of µ in different encodings is:

```
ASCII (ISO-8859-1) : 0xB5

UTF-8 : 0xC2B5

UTF-16 (= Java) : 0x00B5
```

Now I did some investigations to see which bytes the database actually sees. Therefor I tried a sql-statement like this:

```
select convert(VARBINARY(MAX), value), --  selects µ from database table
       convert(VARBINARY(MAX), N'µ'),  --  selects µ from literal
       convert(VARBINARY(MAX), ?)      --  selects µ from bind parameter
from ...
```

The result for the three values is:

```
B500
B500
C200B500     <-- Here is the problem!
```

So, the internal representation of µ in the database and as NVARCHAR literal is B500.

Now we can't understand what is going on here. We have the value of 'µ' in a Java variable (which should internally be 0x00B5). When it is passed as bind variable, then is seems as if it is converted to UTF-8 (which makes byte sequence 0xC2B5), and then the database treats it as if it were two characters, making the sequence of characters C200B500 from it.

To make things even more confusing:

(1) On an other machine with a different database the same code works like expected. The result of the three lines is B500/B500/B500, so the bind variable is converted to be a proper B500.

(2) On the same machine, the same database but a different program (but using the same jdbc driver library and the same connect parameters) this *also* works as expected, giving the result of B500/B500/B500.

Some additional facts, maybe they are important:
The database is Sql Server 2014
Java is Java 7
The application in question is a webapp running in Tomcat 7.
Jdbc library is sqljdbc 4.2

Any help to sort this out is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a short, but complete repro of the problem?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question with a [mcve]. Something in your problematic code is forcing UTF-8 encoding and sending the `µ` as `byte[]` instead of `String`. (SQL Server doesn't use UTF-8 for Unicode; it uses UTF-16LE.)

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of the driver? The last version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver that supports Java 7 is 6.4.0. Also, make sure that you are using the proper value of `µ` in your code. Possibly due to incorrect source encoding, the value might have been entered in UTF-8, but compiled as windows-1252 (thus yielding the two characters `Âµ` (0xc2b5) instead). Try using the unicode escape `\u00B5` in your code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found the solution. It did not at all have something to do with Sql Server or binding, but instead...

Tomcat 7 is not running in UTF-8 mode by default (I wasn't aware of that). The µ we are talking about comes from an other application that is providing this value via webservice calls. However, *this* application is using UTF-8 as default. So, it was sending an UTF-8 µ, but the webservice did not expect UTF-8 and thought that it would be two characters, and treated them like this, filling the internal String variable with the character for 0xC2 and 0xB5 (which is, for Sql Server, C200B500).

Comment: Question for the stackoverflow experts: How should I modify this question to make it useful (as it does not have to do with Sql Server as initially thought) ?

Comment: This specific area should be explored from security perspective.